# Abstract or annotated class instead interface as MXBean

Tags: java, class, interface, jmx

Is there a way to use abstract or annotated class as MXBean descriptor? I have interface like:

```
@MXBean
public interface Peer {
    public String getName();
}
```

and want that MXBean to be combined in class with more local-side-only methods like:

```
public class PeerCombinedMXBean {
    // Expose this as MXBean attribute
    public String getName() { ... }

    // This method is local-instance-oriented
    public boolean isValid() { ... }
}
```

I need model like above to avoid chain-in proxy object instead to use complex half-proxified instance like:

```
PeerCombinedMXBean peer = JMX.newMXBeanProxy(connection, name, PeerCombinedMXBean.class);
if (peer.isValid()) System.out.println(peer.getName());
```

---

### Edit

This question is related to [java.net article](http://weblogs.java.net/blog/emcmanus/archive/2007/08/defining_mbeans.html). What is they progress? Can I use MBeans with annotation safely now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I ended up doing for this was writing a custom annotation that you place on a method or property.  Then, I implemented the [DynamicMBean interface](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/javax/management/DynamicMBean.html) in such a way that it parsed out the annotations on the class in question and then registers them with the PlatformMBeanServer.  As far as I know, there are no public implementations of this available, I also searched extensively about this topic before I just did it myself.

For example, here is the class that I wish to manage from JConsole:

```
public class Foo
{
  // In JMX Console
  @Managed
  private boolean isBar;

  // Not in JMX Console
  private boolean isFoo;

  // In JMX Console
  @Managed
  public String getClassName()
  {
    return Foo.class.getName();
  }
}
```

Then, when my application starts up, I register an instance of this class using my implementation of [DynamicMBean](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/javax/management/DynamicMBean.html) and parse out the annotations.

Comment: I'm reflect about this too, but it is too many code need to be written by now, so I catch up on this idea later if I have time.

Comment: BTW. How do you create proxyfied instance of class (not interface)? What interface is for this or where look for it?

Comment: You mean for a JMX client to use?  I suppose you could use reflection and the Proxy class to dynamically generate one.